# Swift - Cast Int into enum:Int

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am very new to Swift (got started this week) and I'm migrating my app from Objective-C. I have basically the following code in Objective-C that works fine:

```
typedef enum : int {
    MyTimeFilter1Hour = 1,
    MyTimeFilter1Day = 2,
    MyTimeFilter7Day = 3,
    MyTimeFilter1Month = 4,
} MyTimeFilter;

...

- (void)selectFilter:(id)sender
{
    self.timeFilterSelected = (MyTimeFilter)((UIButton *)sender).tag;
    [self closeAnimated:YES];
}
```

When translating it to Swift, I did the following:

```
enum MyTimeFilter : Int {
    case OneHour = 1
    case OneDay = 2
    case SevenDays = 3
    case OneMonth = 4
}

...

@IBAction func selectFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.timeFilterSelected = (sender as UIButton).tag as MyTimeFilter
    self.close(true)
}
```

By doing that, I get the error :

> 'Int' is not convertible to 'MyTimeFilter'

I don't know if my approach (using the tag property) is the best, but anyway I need to do this kind of casting in different places in my app. Does anyone have an idea of how to get rid of this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Also note that instead of `(sender as UIButton)`, you can just change the method signature to take in a `UIButton` instead of `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Use the `rawValue` initializer: it's an initializer automatically generated for `enum`s.

```
self.timeFilterSelected = MyTimeFilter(rawValue: (sender as UIButton).tag)!
```

see: [The Swift Programming Language § Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

---

NOTE: This answer has changed. Earlier version of Swift use the class method `fromRaw()` to convert raw values to enumerated values.

Comment: Also note that if the sender's tag doesn't correspond to an enum value, this will cause a crash due to the `!`.

Comment: I'd say crashing is the best way to catch a bug in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Also for those wondering how you can convert an enum back to an Integer, you can do the following:

```
enum MyTimeFilter : Int {
    case OneHour = 1
    case OneDay = 2
    case SevenDays = 3
    case OneMonth = 4
}

let currentValue = .One
let intValue = currentValue.rawValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
@IBAction func selectFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
    timeFilterSelected = MyTimeFilter(rawValue: sender.tag)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

elaborating on Jeffery Thomas's answer. 
to be safe place a guard statement unwrap the cast before using it,
this will avoid crashes

```
   @IBAction func selectFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
     guard let filter = MyTimeFilter(rawValue: (sender as UIButton).tag) else { 
        return
    }
        timeFilterSelected = filter
     }
```