# How to cast / assign one enum value to another enum

Tags: c, enums

I have 2 enums in 2 different modules that have exactly same value-set. How can I cast one to another?

```
typedef EnumA{
a_dog = 0,
a_cat = 1
} EnumA;

typedef EnumB{
b_dog = 0,
b_cat = 1
} EnumB;

EnumA a = a_dog;
EnumB b;

b = a;
```

Such an assignment is resulting in a warning: enumerated type mixed with another type
Can I avoid switch-case by typecasting, like say

```
b = (int)a;
```

or

```
b = (EnumB)a;
```

Comment: Have you tried any of that?

Comment: If both have exactly the same value-set, why do you have them both defined at all? Just define one and use that one in both modules.

Anyway, casting one enum to another is not always a good idea. It should work though.

Comment: Which compiler/tool (with what options) causes the warning? There isn't any required by the standard (and `gcc -std=c99 -pedantc -Wall -Wextra` doesn't emit one).

Comment: I have not tried either. I use gmake

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made a working code from your question. You have missed the `enum` from your type definitions.

```
typedef enum EnumA
{
    a_dog = 0,
    a_cat = 1
} EnumA;

typedef enum EnumB
{
    b_dog = 0,
    b_cat = 1
} EnumB;

int main()
{
    EnumA a = a_dog;
    EnumB b;

    b = (EnumB) a;
    printf("%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

The code `b = a` also works properly without the cast. Also `b = (int) a;` is working - at least in C11, becuse `enum`s are really just integers. Anyway, IMHO it is good practice to make an explicite cast.

Comment: In swift we can't do that do you have any workaround for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276775/swift-cast-int-into-enumint

Answer (score 2):

`enum` types are integer types and you are allowed to assign any integer value to any integer object.

This is valid and no diagnostic is required by the Standard. Nevertheless some implementations warn when you try to mix up different `enum` types.

To silent the warning the best is to not mix up the enum types, but otherwise I would recommend to cast it to the enum type.

```
 b = (EnumB)a;
```

Except if your compiler is really smart, this:

```
b = (int)a;
```

should also work as `enum` constant are of type `int` and the compiler is not supposed to warn when the right `enum` constant (type `int`) is assigned to the right associated `enum` type.