# How to parse enum with JASON pod?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I get JSON from a server. For parsing, I use [JASON](https://github.com/delba/JASON)
 library.
How can I parse JSON with enum value?

Example:

```
{
        ...
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "user_type": "basic"
        ...
}
```

Where 'user_type':

```
enum UserType {
  case basic
  case pro
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by parsing? Do you want to get a value `user_type` from JSON store in enum variable?

Comment: yes, you're right

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store value of `user_type` in enum:

Change your enum variable type into string:

```
enum UserType: String {
  case basic = "basic"
  case pro = "pro"
}
```

**Solution, without using JASON**

Store your JSON into dictionary type variable:

```
let jsonVar = [
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "user_type": "basic"
] as [String : Any]
```

Now, get a value from dictionary variable and create enum variable using raw value:

```
if let user_type = jsonVar["user_type"] as? String {
   let usertype = UserType(rawValue: user_type)
}
```

**Solution, using JASON**

```
let json = [
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "user_type": "basic"
] as AnyObject


let jasonVar = JSON(json) 

if let user_type:String = jasonVar["user_type"].string {
   let usertype = UserType(rawValue: user_type)
}
```

Comment: how can I do it with JASON lib?

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [How to get enum from raw value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184795/how-to-get-enum-from-raw-value-in-swift)

```
 enum TestEnum: String {
      case Name = "Name"
      case Gender = "Gender"
      case Birth = "Birth Day"
    }

    let name = TestEnum(rawValue: "Name")!       //Name
    let gender = TestEnum(rawValue: "Gender")!   //Gender
    let birth = TestEnum(rawValue: "Birth Day")! //Birth
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Swift 4 there is useful default JSONDecoder. With your example:

```
import Foundation

let  jsonDict = [
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"user_type": "basic"
]

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: [])

enum UserType: String, Codable {
    case basic
    case pro
}

struct User: Codable {
    let firstName : String
    let lastName: String
    let userType: UserType

enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case firstName = "first_name"
    case lastName = "last_name"
    case userType = "user_type"
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let user = try! decoder.decode(User.self, from: jsonData)

print(user)
```