# How to get the name of an enumeration case by its raw value in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

#### Using Xcode 9.4.1 and Swift 4.1

Having an enumeration with multiple cases from type Int, how can I print the case name by its rawValue?

```
public enum TestEnum : UInt16{
case ONE    = 0x6E71
case TWO    = 0x0002
case THREE  = 0x0000
}
```

I am accessing the Enum by the rawValue:

```
print("\nCommand Type = 0x" + String(format:"%02X", someObject.getTestEnum.rawValue))
/*this prints: Command Type = 0x6E71
if the given Integer value from someObject.TestEnum is 28273*/
```

Now I additionally want to print "ONE" after the HEX value.

I am aware of the Question: [How to get the name of enumeration value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113126/how-to-get-the-name-of-enumeration-value-in-swift)
but this is something different because I want to determine the case name by the cases raw value instead of the enumeration value by itself.

Desired Output:

**Command Type = 0x6E71, ONE**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get enum from raw value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184795/how-to-get-enum-from-raw-value-in-swift)

Comment: Please add/print exact output in your question, that you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get the case name as as `String` as the enum's type isn't `String`, so you'll need to add a method to return it yourself…

```
public enum TestEnum: UInt16, CustomStringConvertible {
    case ONE = 0x6E71
    case TWO = 0x0002
    case THREE = 0x0000

    public var description: String {
        let value = String(format:"%02X", rawValue)
        return "Command Type = 0x" + value + ", \(name)"
    }

    private var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .ONE: return "ONE"
        case .TWO: return "TWO"
        case .THREE: return "THREE"
        }
    }
}

print(TestEnum.ONE)

// Command Type = 0x6E71, ONE
```

Answer (score 10):

You can create an enum value from its rawValue and get its case String using `String.init(describing:)`.

```
public enum TestEnum : UInt16 {
    case ONE    = 0x6E71
    case TWO    = 0x0002
    case THREE  = 0x0000
}

let enumRawValue: UInt16 = 0x6E71

if let enumValue = TestEnum(rawValue: enumRawValue) {
    print(String(describing: enumValue)) //-> ONE
} else {
    print("---")
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: Fantastic answer! Tried using CaseIterable and Mirror, but no luck. This did the trick!!!

Comment: Well, I found an edge case. It won't work if the enum adopts "CodingKey" :-(