# How to extract name of enum case of `UIBlurEffect.Style` in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I am trying to extract programmatically the names of the enum cases of `UIBlurEffect.Style` which have a `rawValue` of `Int` not `String`.  The names in an array would be `["extraLight","light","dark","regular",...]`

Doing `print(UIBlurEffect.Style.systemChromeMaterialLight)` doesn't print `systemChromeMaterialLight` instead it prints `UIBlurEffectStyle`

I tried also using `Mirror` but this yields a name of `__C.UIBlurEffectStyle`

Example code of what I am trying to do:

```
let myStyles : [UIBlurEffect.Style] = [.light, .dark, .regular, .prominent]
for style in myStyles {
  print(style) // does not work, produces "UIBlurEffectStyle"
  myFunction(styleName: String(reflecting: style)) // does not work, produces "UIBlurEffectStyle"
  myFunction(styleName: String(describing: style)) // does not work, produces "UIBlurEffectStyle"
  myFunction(styleName: "\(style)") // does not work, produces "UIBlurEffectStyle"
}
```

I am using Swift 5, iOS 14, and Xcode 12.3

For reference, the enum is defined as follows by Apple:

```
extension UIBlurEffect {
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public enum Style : Int {
        case extraLight = 0
        case light = 1
        case dark = 2
        
        @available(iOS 10.0, *)
        case regular = 4

    ...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52077091/5009432

Comment: @impression7vx doesn't work

Comment: Might have to make a `switch` statement for each case, then you could simply call the description. stackoverflow.com/a/52077091/5009432

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something dynamic that is related to the name on your app so you can show the correct one based on the selection?
If you are, I suggest you create your own local String enum and then add a var or function to get the blur from it instead of trying to reverse this.

But if you really, really need this for some other reason, there is a workaround, which I do not recommend, but it's here in case you want to test it out:

```
let blurStyle = String(describing: UIBlurEffect(style: .systemMaterialDark))
let style = blurStyle.components(separatedBy: "style=").last?.replacingOccurrences(of: "UIBlurEffectStyle", with: "")
print(style) // SystemMaterialDark
```

Creating your own app Style enum:

```
enum AppBlurStyle: String {
    case extraLight
    case dark
    case light
    case regular
    
    var blurEffectStyle: UIBlurEffect.Style {
        switch self {
            case .extraLight: UIBlurEffect.Style.extraLight
            case .dark: UIBlurEffect.Style.dark
            case .light: UIBlurEffect.Style.light
            case .regular: UIBlurEffect.Style.regular
        }
    }
    
    var blurEffect: UIBlurEffect {
        switch self {
            case .extraLight: UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
            case .dark: UIBlurEffect(style:.dark)
            case .light: UIBlurEffect(style:.light)
            case .regular: UIBlurEffect(style:.regular)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can even just extend UIBlurEffect.Style and add a name property, mapping them individually:

```
extension UIBlurEffect.Style {
    var name: String {
        switch self {
            case .extraLight: "extraLight"
            case .dark: "dark"
            case .light: "light"
            case .regular: "regular"
            ...
        }
    }
}
```