# A better way to match error code with enum describing error

Tags: ios, swift

I have an enum describing various error codes that can be returned from a server:

```
public enum LoginError: Int, Error {
  case missingUsername = 30001
  case missingPassword = 30002
  case incorrectPassword = 30003
  case unknownUser = 30005
  case couldNotBeLoaded = 31002
  case sessionExpired = 31001
  case unknownError = 30000
}
```

The server returns the error in the response body. I'm decoding the result and getting the error code, and then matching the error code with the enum:

```
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let loginResult = try decoder.decode(LoginResult.self, from: data)
            
            if loginResult.success {
                return .success(loginResult)
            } else {
                switch loginResult.errorCode as! Error {
                case LoginError.incorrectPassword:
                    return .failure(.incorrectPassword)
                case LoginError.missingUsername:
                    return .failure(.missingUsername)
                case LoginError.missingPassword:
                    return .failure(.missingPassword)
                case LoginError.unknownUser:
                    return .failure(.unknownUser)
                case LoginError.couldNotBeLoaded:
                    return .failure(.couldNotBeLoaded)
                case LoginError.sessionExpired:
                    return .failure(.sessionExpired)
                default:
                    return .failure(.unknownError)
                }
            }
```

For one, this crashes because I can't cast the `LoginError` `Int` type to `Error`, but also, there must be a more elegant way than this long switch statement. I feel like there's some basic bit of Swift syntax I've missed here. Is there a one-liner that could replace this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276775/swift-cast-int-into-enumint

Comment: What about making your `errorCode` in `LoginResult` directly a `LoginError` property?

Comment: @Larme That could be possible. I might be able to change the `LoginResult` Codable struct to decode directly to `LoginError`. Looking that up now.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, comparing to `.rawValue` in the switch statement solves the cast problem but doesn't get rid of the switch statement itself. Tried other commenters suggestion of decoding the error code directly as a `LoginError` but can't seem to work it out.

Comment: ` let errorCode: LoginError` in `LoginResult` & `enum LoginError: Int, Error, Codable` should do the trick. BUT if `errorCode` can have another value, then it decoding will fail. If you can certify the value, instead of your `switch`, you can write `return .failure(loginResult.errorCode)`.

Comment: Else, you could also do: `let loginError = LoginError(rawValue: loginResult.errorCode) ?? .unknow; return .failure(loginError)`.

Comment: @Larme When I did that in Codable it failed silently. Can't stop progressing so going to revisit later.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong, since I couldn't reproduce your attempt. I made it work on my side with a sample, but I don't know the error you get...